# Specify a specific worksheet to open for a Microsoft Excel workbook using a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Microsoft Excel workbook with several worksheets.

Users are directed to this spreadsheet using a hyperlink in an e-mail.

Is there any way of expressing the hyperlink for getting the spreadsheet to open on a particular worksheet?

Answer (score 4):

If you create the link like the following it will work:

```
http://path/to/Workbook.xls#SheetName!a1
```

Comment: Excellent - this works.  One thing to watch out for is if SheetName includes spaces, e.g., Sheet Name - make sure to form the link like this:
http://path/to/Workbook.xls#'Sheet Name'!a1

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Browser downloads file to disk ignoring hashed param, open dialog in excel ignores it too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do this directly.

A hyperlink can open a workbook, but it will always open to the sheet and cell that were selected when it was saved.

You could add a contents sheet with hyperlink formulas to the other sheets

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xls]Sheet2!A10","My internal link text")
```

You will need to make sure that the workbook is save with the Contents sheet selected.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Excel 2007:

I named the exact cell I wanted to open (by just selecting it and then typing the new name in the Name Box, which can be found to the top left).

Then the hyperlink goes [filename with full path]#[cellname] obviously without the brackets.

E.g. http://pathpart1/pathpart2/workbook.xlsm#OpeningCell

"OpeningCell" would be the name I'd given to the cell.

Note that it didn't matter which worksheet I was on when I last saved the file.  With the hyperlink set up like this I get to the exact cell every time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a macro in VBA:

```
Private Sub SetWorksheet()
Worksheets("Worksheet1").Activate
End Sub
```