# Where are possible fragments in Excel URLs documented?

Tags: microsoft-excel, url

When creating links to Excel files it is possible to add a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_fragment) to the URL in order to specify a specific location (e.g. a certain sheet) which should be opened when the link is followed. See, for example, [this question here on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/205728/how-do-you-specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-ms-excel-workbook-using-a).

I am looking for a detailed documentation just what types of fragments are possible (e.g. ranges, named ranges, ...). Google & Co didn't help much, since all the results are about linking the content of cells between different Excel sheets (which is not what I'm after).

So:

> In a link `http://somehost.com/some_excel_file.xls#fragment`, what are valid values for `fragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is documented by Microsoft in [Article ID: 197922](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197922) which covers what you are trying to do. Basically, after the `#` you place the tab name then `!`followed by the cell reference.

`http://somehost.com/some_excel_file.xls#TabName!A1`

If you are doing this in HTML of course you will use...

`<a href="http://somehost.com/some_excel_file.xls#TabName!A1">
This link will open the Excel file to the named tab with the focus on
cell A1</a>`.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.