# Is it possible to share a hyperlink in outlook email to a specific excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010, hyperlink

I have an Excel workbook which I can shared by sending a hyperlink to this file by e-mail. But I do not just want to share the file, but link specifically to a certain worksheet.

I know that linking within excel files to specific worksheets is possible (I have done that in other files) but is this also possible in a hyperlink in an email? The way I have tried that, did not give the desired result.

I have tried this:

```
\\...\Marktdata\Nielsen\Nielsen Periode rapportage\!Periode rapportage.xlsm#'fabrikanten-retailers'
```

This does not work: it prompts an error telling me:

> General Error: the file cannot be found.

When I only link to the file, the hyperlink works perfectly:

```
\\...\Marktdata\Nielsen\Nielsen Periode rapportage\!Periode rapportage.xlsm
```

Comment: Yes, but the recipient of the email must have access to the target of the link.

Comment: I tried several methods but did not succeed. How can I create a working hyperlink?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you specify a specific worksheet to open for a MS Excel workbook using a hyperlink?](http://superuser.com/questions/205728/how-do-you-specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-ms-excel-workbook-using-a)

Comment: `http://path/to/Workbook.xls#SheetName!a1`

Comment: It has been some time ago but today I ran into the same situation and found my own question from 3 years ago. I used this to insert to the hyperlink in the email: \\biohorma.local\dfs\Werkgroep\Commercie\Marktdata\Periode rapportages\IRi\2018\Periode rapportage Zelfzorg P8.xlsb#TOP10 per segment (zelfzorg) but it causes an error. I also do not think my question is a duplicate, as the other question was specifically aimed at linking in Excel